# How do I create page numbers in XSLT?

Tags: xml, stylesheet, page-numbering, rtf

Ive created a c# application which gets an xml file and a xslt file and creates an rtf document. This rtf document is to have a header a footer and page numbers but I can't figure out how to do this in xslt.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Please post relevant code & input.

Comment: The fact that you're using XSLT is probably irrelevant. You'll just need to output the rich text that generates the page number. A lot about Rich Text (including page numbers) can be found in the specs: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm  Search for `Page Numbers` on that page to find a bunch of relevant options.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need something to be used in XSL, then you can have a block in the footer region (xsl-region-after) and within that block you can have this snippet.

```
  <fo:block text-align="right"><fo:page-number format="1"/><fo:page-number-citation format="1" ref-id="last-page"/></fo:block>
```

not to forget to include the following snippet in the

<

```
fo:block id="last-page"/> just before the  </fo:page-sequence>
```

HTH