# Header and footer and page numbers using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, header, page-numbering

Ive created a c# application which gets an xml file and a xslt file and creates a word document. This word document is to have a header a footer and page numbers but I can't figure out how to format this in xslt.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838364/how-do-i-create-page-numbers-in-xslt

Answer (score -1):

If you specifically need something to be used in XSL, then you can have a block in the footer region (xsl-region-after) and within that block you can have this snippet.

```
<fo:block text-align="right"><fo:page-number format="1"/><fo:page-number-citation format="1" ref-id="last-page"/></fo:block>
```

HTH