# Adding header and footer in an XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, xsl-fo

I have an XSLT file which transforms an XML into a word document. My problem is I want to add headers and footer in the document. How do I do it?

My question is basically similar to this [Header and footer and page numbers using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838613/header-and-footer-and-page-numbers-using-xslt).

More help about headers and footers can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_region-after.asp). Basically I need to use these tags but how do I use it in my template? Do I put it in the end or somewhere in the middle? I would also like to change the word page layout to landscape which is portrait be default.

```
<fo:region-before> defines the top region (header)
<fo:region-after> defines the bottom region (footer)
```

Assume this is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above example has been copied from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

Comment: can you get your question a little more context? maybe provide your input document, the transformation you have currently, the expected results. Can be fragments too. hard to understand otherwise

Comment: I have included an example XSLT. I have no problem pulling the data. My only problem is putting in header and footers.

Comment: wait a minute... something doesn't add up. why would you need xsl-fo headers/footers in the HTML? you would have to frame your problem to be close to what you're really struggling with.

Comment: What has `xsl:fo` to do with Word?

Comment: I will use `xsl:of` in xslt template. This template is run by a third party software and creates a word document out of this template.

Comment: You say that you have an XSLT file "which transfroms an XML into a word document". Why don't you show us that XSLT file instead of copying an unrelated snippet from w3schools into your question?

Comment: The help I need with is `how to use footer and header in xslt template`. I really dont need help pulling the data. It is mostly about syntax. Where do I put the tags? Ppl dont usually post the company code if there is no need of. I am not sure how would that make it a better question. It is not related to my comopany at all.

Comment: I included the header of my orig xslt. Now the first 8 lines are exactly match to my own file.The rest is same thing, I am creating a table and referencing node in a loop. I need to include footer though.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: The XSLT you have included produces **HTML**. This is completely irrelevant to your stated wish to use `fo:region-before` and `fo:region-after`, which are constructs of **XSL-FO**.

Comment: @mzjn, as far as I know, it **does create a word template for me**. I know I might have to change it but I dont know what to change and where to change.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter The point is that xsl-fo and html usually don't mingle. Either you produce xsl-fo entirely with your xslt or, just html. I'd be surprised if you processor would accept xsl-fo within html, and do something sensible with it.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter Be aware that Word is capable of opening HTML, but that doesn't support headers and footers as far as I know. Alternatives could be generating xsl-fo entirely, and use an fo processor that can produce something like RTF. Or produce a proper Word document in one of the XML syntaxes, Word 2003 XML for instance.

Comment: @grtjn, I am working on that line. I dont have to have HTML ouput. It is not required. I need to added footer now matter how. A short example is needed I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As said in plenty comments, don't generate HTML, but either XSL-FO or Word XML entirely. Since Word XML is the most direct approach, I'll help you with the smallest sample I could think of that returns something similar to your HTML, but with header and footer. Actually, I just opened a resulting HTML in Word, saved that as Word XML, added header and footer, and got rid of most of the superflues XML tagging Word automatically adds.

Put the following inside your root xsl template, add a for each around the table rows, and fill header/footer dynamically the way you like..

```
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve">

<w:docPr>
<w:view w:val="print"/>
<w:zoom w:percent="100"/>
</w:docPr>

<w:styles>
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading2">
<w:name w:val="heading 2"/>
<wx:uiName wx:val="Heading 2"/>
<w:basedOn w:val="Standaard"/>
<w:pPr>
<w:spacing w:before="100" w:before-autospacing="on" w:after="100" w:after-autospacing="on"/>
<w:outlineLvl w:val="1"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:b/>
<w:sz w:val="36"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:style>

<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Headertext">
<w:name w:val="header"/>
<wx:uiName wx:val="Header text"/>
<w:basedOn w:val="Standaard"/>
<w:pPr>
<w:tabs>
<w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="4536"/>
<w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="9072"/>
</w:tabs>
</w:pPr>
</w:style>

<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Footertext">
<w:name w:val="footer"/>
<wx:uiName wx:val="Footer text"/>
<w:basedOn w:val="Standaard"/>
<w:pPr>
<w:tabs>
<w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="4536"/>
<w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="9072"/>
</w:tabs>
</w:pPr>
</w:style>
</w:styles>

<w:body>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:t>My CD Collection</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>

<w:tbl>
<w:tblPr>
<w:tblW w:w="5000" w:type="pct"/>
<w:tblCellSpacing w:w="15" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tblBorders>
<w:top w:val="outset" w:sz="6" wx:bdrwidth="15" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:left w:val="outset" w:sz="6" wx:bdrwidth="15" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:bottom w:val="outset" w:sz="6" wx:bdrwidth="15" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:right w:val="outset" w:sz="6" wx:bdrwidth="15" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
</w:tblBorders>
<w:tblCellMar>
<w:top w:w="15" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:left w:w="15" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:bottom w:w="15" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:right w:w="15" w:type="dxa"/>
</w:tblCellMar>
<w:tblLook w:val="04A0"/>
</w:tblPr>
<w:tr>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Title</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Artist</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>title1</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>artist1</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>title2</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>artist2</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>
</w:tbl>

<w:p />

<w:hdr w:type="odd">
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Headertext"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:t>Header text</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:tab/>
<w:t>center</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:tab/>
<w:t>right</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:hdr>

<w:ftr w:type="odd">
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Footertext"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:t>left</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:tab/>
<w:t>Footer text</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:tab/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:instrText>PAGE   \* MERGEFORMAT</w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:t>1</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:ftr>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

It also helps to make sure the following processing-instruction gets added before the root element:

```
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
```

HTH!

Comment: An alternative to producing HTML would be to produce a "Flat" OPC file (via XSLT), which Word 2007/2010 can read/write.

Comment: @jason Flat OPC is more complex than Word 2003 XML.

Comment: Flat OPC is a modern format which can be readily transformed to/from standards based WordML (ie ECMA 376).  Word 2003 XML is now 10 years old, and although the schema is available, I don't think there is a public spec for it.

Comment: [`Office 2003: XML Reference Schemas`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101)